# Verify email address on sign up using NodeJs, ExpressJs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, meanjs

I'm new with MeanJS framework (MongoDb, ExpressJS,NodeJS and AngularJS), and I need your help to explain me how can I send an email containing a link for the  new user to verify his address?

Answer (score 4):

Use [nodemailer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer).

A quick example taken from its README:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport();
transporter.sendMail({
    from: 'sender@address',
    to: 'receiver@address',
    subject: 'hello',
    text: 'hello world!'
});
```

Sending emails through SMTP is also possible (using Gmail, Hotmail, etc.):

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'sender@gmail.com',
        pass: 'password'
    }
});
transporter.sendMail({
    from: 'sender@address',
    to: 'receiver@address',
    subject: 'hello',
    text: 'hello world!'
});
```

Comment: Thank you for youre responding.
But how can i valid his new account when he clicks in the link ?!

Comment: What I do is I have a database table solely for storing sign up tokens. So when you send the link `http://something.com/confirm?email=[email]&token=[token]` the server can see whether there is a match in the database.

Comment: im new with nodejs can you give me more details since validate inscription with your own email until validation of your new account please ?

Comment: emm I don't exactly understand the question, but I will try to explain.

Comment: There should probably be a form where user can fill in email address and password and things, a POST request is then sent to the server, and the server creates a user profile with `verified=false`, then inserts into a `tokens` table `email`, `token`, and `expiry` fields. The server then sends the user an email using `transporter.sendMail`, the email body (`text`) contains a link as described 3 comments ago. The user clicks on the link and the server verifies the email and the token, and removes/invalidates the document in the `tokens` table if the verification passes.

Comment: thank you very much. 
Can you give me an example for how can i generate token user ?

Comment: [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yphp5njz/) is a simple example of generating a token (virtually unique all the time). And [here](https://github.com/braitsch/node-login) is a complete user login system you can reference from.

Comment: Thnak you lot Ben :)